# How is cURL related to web services?

Tags: php

well...just about all I needed to say...lookie here, I'm a total noob in web programming so go easy on me..and oh...if ever it is...could you point me to a simple example? i've worked wiht cURL on a payment API (Authorize.net) but I can't seem to get the picture of how it applies to web services

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL

Comment: what kind of web service are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`cURL`](http://php.net/curl) is a library used to retrieve remote URLs.

There are plenty of other ways to do this in PHP, for instance using [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/file_get_contents) but cURL offers much more flexibility.

It doesn't do anything *special* with web services - all it does is request URLs. Depending on the type of service you're using you might want to look at the PEAR SOAP module, PHP's [`SOAP`](http://php.net/soap) classes or PHP's [XML-RPC](http://php.net/xml-rpc) functions.

Comment: There is cURL and there is libcurl. You can link libcurl in your application and thus enable it to access URLs on the web. cURL is a command-line interface to libcurl (cf. http://curl.haxx.se/).

Comment: I'm so silly; didn't realize this was about php's curl. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

you can use curl to fetch a url (usually with a post request), and use the data that was fetched in you application.

curl operates as a client or useragent, in much the same way as requesting data from a website would be done from a web browser.

if you are doing strictly get requests there are other simpler was then curl, but curl gives a lot more flexibility, such as reading headers, raw data, etc